# Populating attributes while creating polygons in for-loop from CSV using PyQGIS

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, csv, pyqgis-3

I have a working script that builds rectangles from a CSV using [@Kadir Sahbaz's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396509/17482) and [@Ben W's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396507/17482)

I'm wanting to pass non-geometry attributes as well. This runs and creates the fields but with `NULL` values:

```py
srcFile = "D:\\Data\\filename.csv"

layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:2193", "Polygons", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ViewName',QVariant.String, '', 50, 0),
                        QgsField('FigName',QVariant.String, '', 10, 0)])
layer.updateFields()

with open(srcFile,'r') as infile:
    rect = infile.readlines()
    
for b in rect[1:]:
    parts = b.split(',')

    #### Coordinates coming from CSV ####
    xMin = float(parts[2])
    yMin = float(parts[3])
    xMax = float(parts[4])
    yMax = float(parts[5])

    rect = QgsRectangle(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax)
    polygon = QgsGeometry.fromRect(rect)
    
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(polygon)

    provider.addFeatures([feature]) 
 
    fields = QgsFields()
    feature.setFields(fields)
    feature['ViewName'] = parts[0]
    feature['FigName'] = parts[-2]

    provider.addAttributes(fields)
    layer.updateFields()
```

I'm still getting `NULL` values. FWIW...if I run @Ben W's code, change the with statement to:

```
with edit(layer):
    print(parts[0],parts[-2])
    provider.addFeatures([feature])
    t = provider.changeAttributeValues({feature.id(): {f1: parts[0], f2: parts[-2]}})
    print(t)
```

The values from the CSV are appearing and `.changeAttributeValues` appears to running properly:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You set feature fields to empty `QgsFields`.

```py
fields = QgsFields() # fields is empty
feature.setFields(fields) # you set the empty fields
```

Instead, pass `layer.fields()` to `QgsFeature`.

```py
feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
```

You also  get `NULL` values, because you add the feature to the layer (`provider.addFeatures([feature])`) before you populate the fields.

Use this script:

```py
srcFile = "D:\\Data\\filename.csv"

layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:2193", "Polygons", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ViewName',QVariant.String, '', 50, 0),
                        QgsField('FigName',QVariant.String, '', 10, 0)])
layer.updateFields()

with open(srcFile,'r') as infile:
    rows = infile.readlines()

for r in rows:
    parts = r.split(',')

    xMin = float(parts[2])
    yMin = float(parts[3])
    xMax = float(parts[4])
    yMax = float(parts[5])

    rect = QgsRectangle(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax)
    polygon = QgsGeometry.fromRect(rect)
    
    feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feature.setGeometry(polygon)
    feature['ViewName'] = parts[0]
    feature['FigName'] = parts[-2]
    provider.addFeatures([feature])
```

Sample CSV:

```py
1,0, 1804512.8556, 5453390.58088, 1813512.8556, 5461390.58088, yedi1, sekiz1, dokuz1
2,0, 1814512.8556, 5473390.58088, 1823512.8556, 5471390.58088, yedi2, sekiz2, dokuz2
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I had to re-add the FOR loop slice to skip my header row, but this works...and with a minimal # of lines. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I prefer to use the `changeAttributeValues()` method of `QgsVectorDataProvider` (see API docs [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a99a5d01c33c1cadb7ae9209b68cd8743)) as I find it more reliable. This method takes an attributes map which is basically a dictionary where the key is a feature id and the value is a *second* dictionary comprising field indexes as keys and the new attributes as values.

I have tested this starting with a csv file with the following structure:

[image]

After running the following code:

```py
srcFile = 'D:\\Data\\filename.csv'

layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:2193", "Polygons", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ViewName',QVariant.String, '', 50, 0),
                        QgsField('FigName',QVariant.String, '', 10, 0)])
layer.updateFields()
f1 = layer.fields().lookupField('ViewName')
f2 = layer.fields().lookupField('FigName')
fid = 1

with open(srcFile,'r') as infile:
    csv_lines = infile.readlines()[1:]

for line in csv_lines:
    line = line.split(',')
    #### Coordinates coming from CSV ####
    xMin = float(line[2])
    yMin = float(line[3])
    xMax = float(line[4])
    yMax = float(line[5])

    rect = QgsRectangle(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax)
    polygon = QgsGeometry.fromRect(rect)
    
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(polygon)
    
    with edit(layer):
        provider.addFeatures([feature])
        atts = {f1: line[0], f2: line[-2]}
        provider.changeAttributeValues({fid: atts})
        fid += 1
```

The resulting layer and attribute table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: cheers for reply.  I'm still getting NULLs.  I've updated your with statement in my post with results

Comment: @CreekGeek, the problem was incrementing the feature id in the attributes map. I have thoroughly tested this and edited my answer. The other answers probably suit you better, but as a matter of pride I was compelled to provide an alternative working solution! ;-)

Comment: Tested it on my end and totally good.  I appreciate the effort (and pride in your work). Pretty awesome to get three different answers, all of which are viable.  I'm new to QGIS, but already digging it way more than Arc/arcpy. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I have had this problem too. You have:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:2193", "Polygons", "memory")
```

Maybe add the attribute definitions into the uri.

```
uri = 'LineString?crs= EPSG:2193&field=id:integer&field=name:String(40)&field=age:double'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Polygons", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addFeatures(features)
pr.updateExtents()
vl.updateExtents()
```

The `features` array would contain features that have both geometry and attributes defined.

In a loop:

```
feature = QgsFeature()
ID = 1
name = 'Dog'
age = 4.36
g = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points)
a = [int(ID), name, age]
feature.setGeometry(g)
feature.setAttributes(a)
features.add(feature)
```

- This way works reliably for me.
- if you get the uri syntax wrong, you usually get NULL attribute values
- Every time I have a problem, it has always been with the uri syntax not matching the real attributes (make sure an `int` is actually an `int`, as shown above)

Comment: I like the idea of building it in early and just passing a list.  Upvoting and will keep this one in my back pocket as the Kadir's answer required fewer mods.  Cheers!