# Getting bounding box polygons from xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax in attribute table

Tags: qgis, vector, extents, polygon-creation

I have a CSV file with bbox extents in xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax format. I can import these as pairs of delimited text layers and see the diagonal extents of these boxes on my map document.

Can I take that one step further and turn them into boxes? Each xmin,ymin and xmax, ymax pair have a unique `"ID"` so they can be matched.

Comment: Run `points to path`, then `lines to polygons`.

Comment: Would that not just create a diagonal line?

Comment: Solution using PyQGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396597/99589

Answer (score 3):

You can run [geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) from processing toolbox. Choose "polygon" as output and use this expression:

```
make_polygon(
make_line(
make_point("xmin","ymax"), -- upper left
make_point("xmax","ymax"), -- upper right
make_point("xmax","ymin"), -- lower right
make_point("xmin","ymin"), -- lower left
make_point("xmin","ymax") -- upper left (closing point)
)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the csv-layer and create a bounding box with either [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) using the function [bounds](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#bounds) with this expression:

```
bounds (collect ($geometry, group_by:=id))
```

*The result using Geometry generator:*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there is a CSV file called 'test' with its content, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Drag&drop your CSV into QGIS, so it is viewable in the Layers Panel

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Create a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

With the following query, it is possible to *turn the extents in xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax into boxes*.

```sql
SELECT "id", "name",
        make_polygon(
            make_line(
                make_point("xmin","ymax"),
                make_point("xmax","ymax"),
                make_point("xmax","ymin"),
                make_point("xmin","ymin")
                )
            ) AS geom
FROM "test"
```

and get the desired output:

[image: result]